# Query Reading data from a remote database in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases one remote and the local ...  the remote db has an ip address lets say

```
      Data Source = 172.16.10.118;
      Database    = AGD;
      user id     = payrol;
      password    = p_11t@x123
```

I tried this below but did not work

```
   USE [172.16.10.118]
   GO

   SELECT [AGD].dbo.[AID]
      ,[UID]
      ,[VoteCode]
   FROM [dbo].[Assignments]
   GO
```

.. how do i solve this riddle

Comment: You need to create a linked server, and then use 4 part naming. `USE [172.16.10.118]` would attempt to use a *database* called `172.16.10.118` on the instance you are connected to, not change the context of the instance.

Comment: Here's the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16